# ¿Cual es la forma más eficiente para rellenar varios objetos de la misma clase?

Tags: java, android

Buenas, tengo una especie de toolkit que trabaja siempre con los mismos valores, ahora lo tengo en una array enorme en el main y se que está mal. Hoy he querido ponerme a optimizar el código y se me ha ocurrido que lo mejor es crear una clase con los atributos y de ahí generar una lista de mi clase. Mi pregunta es, cual sería la forma más optima de rellenar dicha lista?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deseas agregar varios elementos de clase a una lista, puedes crear un **[ArrayList](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html)** y agregar varias instancias de tu clase para crear un listado.

```
List <ClaseAlgo> myListado = new ArrayList <ClaseAlgo> ();
```

ahora puedes crear varias instancias de tu Clase y agregarlas a la lista, la clase incluso puede necesitar parametros para inicializarse, en este ejemplo usaremos 2 para la clase `ClaseAlgo`:

```
myListado.add(new ClaseAlgo("primervalor", "segundovalor"));
myListado.add(new ClaseAlgo("a", "b"));
myListado.add(new ClaseAlgo("valor1", "valor2"));
```

al final tendrias un listado de clases de tipo `ClaseAlgo` llamado `myListado`...